# How to attach a file to a dataobject in silverstripe 3

Tags: object, file-upload, silverstripe

I have a simple task that I can't seem to figure out.
In SS3 how can I attach a file to my data object or in other words create a file upload field, and bind that file object to the data object. See example below:

```
class myDataObject extends DataObject{

 public static $db = array(
    'Title' => 'Varchar',
    'Desc' => 'Text',
    'Help Text' => 'HTMLText',
    // 'File Upload (document)' => ???
 );

}//class
```

Note: For now I'd like to do a single file only, but later, on another object I'd like to do multiple files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File cannot be set in $db but in $has_one, as it's a relation to another DataObject.

So you'd need:

```
private static $has_one = array(
  'FileUpload' => 'File'
);
```

I don't think spaces and brackets in the $db or $has_one keys are a good idea, as they are used for database fields. If you want to set a title for the scaffolded fields please use $field_labels.

```
private static $field_labels = array(
  'Title' => 'My fancy title',
  'Desc' => 'Description',
  'has_one_FileUpload' => 'File upload (document)'
);
```

If you want mutliple files you'd need to define it as $has_many insetead of $has_one.

See http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/5-dataobject-relationship-management for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great. Can't vote up because my rep points are too low.

Answer (score 0):

```
'File Upload (document)' => 'File'
```

In the CMS this will give you fields to add files to the cms.
[File Class](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-File.html)

Comment: Thanks for trying much appreciated. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work.
(1) You'll get an error on your /dev/build; The page actually breaks.
(2) After checking the apache logs you'll see why it breaks: 

[error] [client ***.***.***.*] PHP Warning:  DataObject::__construct passed The value 'File Upload (document)'.  It's supposed to be passed an array, taken straight from the database.  Perhaps you should use DataList::create()->First(); instead? in /var/www/html/framework/model/DataObject.php on line 387

Thanks again for your assistance.